# Route to action can not be found with route attribute in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routeattribute

I use asp.net mvc with route attributing and I get this error:

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): No matching action was found on controller 'Test.RequestController'. This can happen when a controller uses RouteAttribute for routing, but no action on that controller matches the request.


public class TestController : Controller
    {      


        [Route("~/api/test")]
        [HttpPost]       
        public async Task<ActionResult> Post(TestRequest r)
        { 
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        }
    }
```

Why is my route with localhost:5555/api/test with POST not found?

That is my default route setup:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        }
```

Comment: You should not have a `~` prefix https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Comment: thanks that worked with web api... where I had a route prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RouteAttribute` should **not** have a leading `~`.